# c++ monitoring function without signature

Tags: c++, function, dll, monitoring

I want to monitor an external program using dll injection
I managed to follow this tutorial and it work
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4118/API-Monitoring-Unleashed

Now i want to be able to monitor any function in the external program without knowing
it signature
I want to be able to copy the parameters sent to the original function and pass them to wrapper function and than back to the original

How it can be done?
I rather not use assembly language because i am not used to it.

Here is some code to demonstrate what i am trying to do:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
void (*pointerToOriginalFunctionForOverride)(...);
void (*copyPointerOfOriginalFucntion)(...);
//let say we dont know the signature of this function
void _cdecl originalFunction(char *s)
{
    printf("%s",s);
}

void functionWrapper(void *first)
{
    printf("Some debug info\n");
    //HERE IS MY PROBLEM
    copyPointerOfOriginalFucntion(?????????????);
}




int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    pointerToOriginalFunctionForOverride = (void (*)(...))(&functionWrapper);
    copyPointerOfOriginalFucntion = (void (*)(...))(&originalFunction);

    //let say this line runs from an external program that we injected a dll into
    pointerToOriginalFunctionForOverride("some text in external program");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible at the C++ level (also your code is disgusting C, not really C++). Your example code won't even work for `functionWrapper` as all variadic arguments must be passed on the stack, but the ABI calls for regular arguments (the first few) to be passed in a register.

You will have to go down to assembly.

Comment: Ok, how can I do it with assembly? I saw this tutorial: http://scottbilas.com/publications/gem-fubi/ but i could not make it work

Answer (score 0):

thanks to to the answer here

http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/39969-hook-function-without-knowing-signature/

> I guess, you almost there with your code... you just need to make your trampoline function not >damaging the stack... firstly the function should be declared naked (without default prologue, in >studio I believe it would be something like __declspec(naked) or something)... secondly you need to >think about do you need to do something after the call to original function... if not, I think it is >better just to simply make a jmp instead of call (using inline assembler or something)...

Here is my code. used vs2012 on windows 7 64bit but 32bit compile. simple win32 console app . hope it helps anyone else

```
#include "stdafx.h"
void originalFunction(int x,int y,int z)
{
    printf("running originalFunction with x=%d\n",x);
}
__declspec(naked) void trampolineFunction()
{
    __asm jmp [originalFunction]
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ((void (*)(...))trampolineFunction)(7,8,9);
     getchar();
    return 0;
}
```